# C++ segmentation fault on programming exercise

Tags: c++, c

I am getting a segmentation fault error when trying to solve this programming marathon C++ exercise but I can't find  the error anywhere:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  int m,n,i,di,x,y;
  char* let;
 cin >> n >> m;
 x=0;
 y=0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
   cin >> let >>di;
   if ((strcmp(let,"S"))||(strcmp(let,"O"))){
    di=(-di);
   }
   if ((strcmp(let,"N"))||(strcmp(let,"S")))
   {
     x=+di;
   }
   if ((strcmp(let,"L"))||(strcmp(let,"O")))
   {
     y=+di;
   }

  if ((y*y)+(x*x)>(m*m))
  {
    cout << "1";
    return 0;
  }
}
  cout << "0";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get a segmentation fault

Comment: Also, you need a book to learn from.  `cin >> let` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You're trying to push data into the memory that the pointer (let) points to, but (let) isn't pointing to anything; hence the segmentation fault.  You'd be better off making let be a string, or if not that, at least a char array.

Comment: If you want to use a single character, use a single character, such as: `char l; cin >> l; if (l == 'N') //...`

Comment: Outside of the problem with let, your strcmp usage `if ((strcmp(let,"S"))||(strcmp(let,"O"))){` looks suspicious to me. Remember if strcmp returns 0 if the strings are equal. <0 if the first sting is less than the second >0 if the first string is greater than the second.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of a `char*`. Stay away from c-strings if aren't familiar with memory management and buffers.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
char* let;
cin >> let
```

stores user input to **the memory pointed to** by `let`.

This is misuse of an uninitialized pointer.  `cin` trusts that you have pointed it to valid memory, but you haven't assigned anything to it.  Where it points to is unknown.

The easiest solution would be to change `let` to a proper C++ `std::string`.